# TFS Eclipse plugin makes Eclipse hang on load workbench

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While loading my workbench in Eclipse with the TFS plugin active, it hangs.  Similarily to this: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85c1d3bc-64c2-4c39-80cb-a210d1ed02a8/tfs-eclipse-plugin-causes-eclipse-to-hang

I removed the com.microsoft folders in plugins, and that fixed the hang on load.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, which happens when the initial connection to the TFS server fails (proxy issues, in my case).

Removing the `com.microsoft` folders in plugins does not work for me, so I remove `org.eclipse.core.resources/` in the project's metadata (`/.metadata/.plugins`).

Note that afterwards it is necessary to reimport the projects (**Import... -> Existing Projects into Workspace**) and share again on TFS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all eclipse project.
2. Rename .project file to any other name or move somewhere else, for all projects in the same workspace.
3. Open workspace in eclipse.
   (project/s status will be closed when you open workspace, because messing .project 
   file)
4. Rename back or place back .project file while eclipse in open.
5. Right click on project and click on Open Project.
6. Get latest from TFS.(if cannot connect to TFS. Check you TFS settings and proxy setting)
7. Close eclipse and reopen workspace.